# Count lines all file and store to file in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I used this command to count lines of each file in a directory:

```
for %G in (*.java) do find /c /v "_+_" %G
```

But the result shows file's names are all uppercase. How can I prevent it? Then, How can I save the result to a file?

Answer (score 0):

`find` seems to convert file names to upper-case. You could use [input redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to avoid `find` to output anything and use `set /P` to return the original file name without case conversion and without trailing line-break, so the returned count is appended to the file name (separated by `:`):

```cmd
set /P ="%~G: " < nul & find /C /V "" < "%~G"
```

To output the result to a file use [output redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
(for %G in ("*.java") do @(set /P ="%~G: " < nul & find /C /V "" < "%~G")) > "output.txt"
```